# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

I have setup one theme in `WordPress` on the server. When I am trying to update the page it gives error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. I have static IP address for my network connection. So, Anyone help me for this?

I have tried many solutions for this but still, it is not working.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Check this link. it might help you.
http://www.udaipurwebdesigner.com/2015/10/08/no-data-received-err_empty_response-wordpress-problem-solved/

Comment: I have already Check this. But, It is not working.

Comment: increase the memory size limit. `ini_set('memory_limit','16M');` and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!!

Sometimes it may be your systems IP issue. Follow these steps

**Process 1**

**Step 1 :** Open CMD Prompt

**Step 2:**

Run below commands one by one.

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /all
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew

netsh int ip set dns
netsh winsock reset
```

Now Restart your PC.

**Process 2**

Problem may be in your wp-login.php , you have to replace **wp-login.php** file with latest WordPress versions **wp-login.ph**p file.

Comment: I can't use CMD Prompt solution like this. Because My network is working on Static IP address. If you have any solution for Static IP address then Please provide to me.

I have already using latest version of WordPress.

Comment: @DhruvinMoradiya Okay Take a Backup of your website along with DB and try to replace new WORDPRESS files. Hope this works..